# Is this a mixture gdb and awk command?

Tags: python, bash, awk, gdb, command

I have come  across this command line when I trying to do the picoctf challenge2019 called times up

I am trying to understand the command as stated below, anyone can clarify this to me? I am kinda lost to understand it

```
gdb ./times-up -ex 'b *generate_challenge+14' -ex 'r' -ex 'p/d $rax' -ex 'c' -ex 'q' | grep '$1 =' | awk '{print $3}'  > ~/answer.txt; ./times-up < ~/answer.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we encourage users on SO to post their efforts in their questions, so kindly add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem and let us know then.

Comment: Hi, I have done research on -ex which also means execute, 'p/d $ra' means print content of $rax in decimal and  awk '{print $3}' means print the third column ? Pls correct me if I'm wrong. thank you

Comment: Looks like you understand each part (gdb, awk). What is missing ? Also, can you provide a link to the 'challenge2019' times-up ?

Comment: I can't provide the actual challenge here as you may need to solve plenty of challenge in order to unlock this challenge. But you may get it from this writes up. [times-up](https://github.com/Dvd848/CTFs/blob/master/2019_picoCTF/Times_Up.md) Here is the link. The method for capturing the flag is different from what the command I inserted here. I got that from a Japanese writes up

Comment: to add on, the command is how I capture the flag. I just need some clarification for the whole command line. Any help there will be highly appreciated